# Hacking AngularJS Form Elements to Change Values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS and can't find a solution to this problem. I have to use an online web form (which I don't control) that is written in Angular 1.4 and I want to inject some JavaScript to change the values in the fields. However, when I try to change the values using JavaScript, they appear correct on the screen, but the old values are the ones that save. I can't find any hidden fields I need to modify.

So, for example, on the form there's a date field with an ID of "end_date." See the code for it below. When I go into the console and type

```
document.getElementById("end_date").value = "2018-11-20 00:00:00"
```

the value on the screen is what I entered but it doesn't save. Any idea what I need to do?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="rawValue" id="end\_date" name="end\_date" 
       class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-date ng-valid-required ng-touched"
       uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" is-open="isOpen"
       ng-required="v.required" close-text="Close" clear-text="Clear"
       current-text="Current" pom-field-change-name="propertyChange">
```

Comment: Try triggering an event on the DOM element, maybe the "change" event

Comment: Sure there is dupes, but you need to manually trigger the change events.

Answer (score 1):

First, make your change to the input, then do:

```
var input = document.getElementById("end_date")
angular.element(input).triggerHandler('change');
```

That should trigger AngularJS to detect the change.

Comment: Thanks. That works! I'm building this into a Chrome extension and one other thing I noticed is that, even if I tell the script not to execute until the document is ready, it still fails to find end_date half of the time when it loads (this happens even if I make it delay for 10 seconds). Is there an angular equivalent of document ready or window loaded I should try to make sure my script sees the end_date field?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I wouldn't know the answer to your second question. I would recommend you post a new question if you cannot find existing answers for it.